# How to force HttpClient to follow HTTPS -> HTTP redirect?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to perform an HTTP GET operation while following redirects.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com");
}
```

Problem is that if the server returns a 302 HTTP code redirecting to `http://...` (not `https`), .NET does not follow it (for security reasons).

How do I force `HttpClient` to follow redirects from HTTPS to HTTP?

Comment: Have you seen [HttpClient does not follow 302 redirects](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24557)?

Comment: The problem is with the HttpClient class of the full Framework. You need to *manually* forbid it when this happens. You can't allow a redirection from Https to Http. You have to grab the Http address and create a new HttpRequestMessage. Prompting the user for confirmation or dis-allowing entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do a little bit of extra work:

```
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com");
    if (new[] {HttpStatusCode.Moved, HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently}.Contains(response.StatusCode))
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(response.Headers.Location);
    }
    // more code
```